# Java Selenium запись видео

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

На сайте есть анимационный блок, анимация которого производится с применением html5, css, и js. Можно ли как то записать эту анимацию в gif? Использую selenium и метод getScreenshotAs.

Изначально задумка была такая: наделать кучу скриншотов, а потом слепить их в gif файл, но проблема в том, что через метод getScreenshotAs скриншот делается очень долго(350-400мс), поэтому нет никакой плавности(получается 3-4 кадра в секунду, а то и меньше).

Вопрос в следующем, можно ли решить как то эту проблему, если нельзя, то может есть какой то другой способ? Варианты с записью экрана не подойдут, потому что это все будет делаться на сервере, без gui.

Answer (score 4):

Можно отрисовывать Selenium на виртуальный фреймбуфер [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) и записывать видео, например, через ffmpeg.

#### Запускаете сервер Xvfb, а в нём браузер:

```
xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num=123 --auth-file /tmp/xvfb.auth -e /dev/stdout -s "-ac -screen 0 1024x768x24" firefox ru.stackoverflow.com
```

> `123` - номер дисплея xserver на ваш выбор
>   `/tmp/xvfb.auth` - путь, по которому будет сохранены авторизационные данные
>   `1024x768x24` - желаемая геометрия фреймбуфера
>   `firefox ru.stackoverflow.com` - открывает этот сайт в Firefox; замените на вашу строку запуска Selenium

#### Чтобы начать писать видео:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :123 -video_size 1024x768 -codec:v libx264 -r 12 video.mp4
```

> `-f x11grab -i :123` - источник видеопотока: xserver, 123й дисплей
>   `-video_size 1024x768` - разрешение видеофайла
>   `libx264` - желаемый видеокодек
>   `-r 12` - частота кадров

Для gif-файла кодек указыать не нужно:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1024x768 -i :123 -r 12 1.gif
```

#### Чтобы снять скриншот (требуется установленный ImageMagick):

```
xwd -display :123 -root | convert xwd:/dev/stdin png:1.png
```

> `-display :123` - все тот же 123й дисплей
>   `-root` - не имеет отношения к пользователю root; указывает, что нужен скриншот всего рабочего стола, а не конкретного окна

Comment: В принципе полностью согласен, но зачем столько телодвижений, если для этого есть прекрасная либа [video-recorder-java](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/video-recorder-java) с поддержкой вплоть до Java 12, заточенная для записи прогона тестов